# Video starts to play when doing F5/refresh/ctrl+F5 JW Player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jwplayer, jwplayer7

I'm using JW player. I have video section with some overlay in my homepage. And video behind that overlay should not autostart. It should play only when I click on that overlay. But currently when I'm doing refresh(F5,ctrl+R, ctrl+F5, etc...) video starts to play a bit. What can be the issue?

Here is my html and js:

```
<div id="mySingleVideoWrapper"> 
    <video id="myVideoFrame">
         <source src="here is my video source" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>

var playerInstance = jwplayer("mySingleVideoWrapper").setup({ 
    image: {my poster image source here},
    width: "100%",  
    fallback:false,
    aspectratio: "16:9",
    logo: { 
        hide: true 
    },
    autostart: false,
    sources: [   
        { 
            file: {my video source here},
        }
    ],
    skin: {
        active: "#f67777",
        name: "glow"
    }
});  

jQuery(".overlay").click(function(){
    var getState = playerInstance.getState();
    jQuery(".overlay").fadeOut(function(){
        jwplayer().play();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example?

Comment: You don't need to include the jQuery click function. If you set JW Player to `autostart: false`, it will play when you click on it.

Comment: How I told in my question, I have an overlay over the video, so overlay won't play video itself if you won't write any code for that! @Josie Keller